# Accessing variables in threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, variables

I'm a beginner in java, and I just started using threads yesterday. I'm having a problem accessing **variables** in a thread, which I want to display.
Long story short, I made a (shitty) clock loop, that runs when the program starts. After certain actions, I have a method that checks the time, but I don't know how to access the **variables** in the thread to make this possible.

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread timeRunning = new Thread(new Clock());
    Clock clock = new Clock();
    Commands command = new Commands();
    timeRunning.start();

    command.whatsTheTime();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    command.whatsTheTime();
```

This is my clock loop:

```
    public class Clock implements Runnable{
public void run(){
    //Time
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours = 0;

    //"Clock" loop
    while(hours < 24) {
        while (minutes < 59) {
            while (seconds < 59) {
                seconds++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                if(seconds == 59) {
                    minutes++;
                    seconds = 0;
                }
                if(minutes == 59) {
                    hours++;
                    minutes = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the "whatsTheTime()" method:

`public void whatsTheTime() {
        System.out.println("The time is: " + clock.hours + ":" + clock.minutes + ":" + clock.seconds);
    }`

But it doesn't work. What I want to know is, how can I access the **seconds**, **minutes** and **hours** from the run() in the Clock class. 
I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I don't know how to access it. I tried googling the solution, but can't seem to find it. I might be seraching for the wrong thing, but as I said, I'm only a few months into java, so searching for the solution is one of the things I need to get better at aswell.

Comment: "I'm a beginner in java, and I just started using threads yesterday." Can I suggest, for the sake of your own sanity, that you should become not a beginner in Java before you attempt to use a most-definitely-not-for-beginners feature like threads.

Comment: Hey! *"But it doesn't work."* is not very descriptive. Please precise that.

Comment: In the code you've shown, `seconds`, `minutes` and `hours` are local variables within the `run()` method. You cannot access local variables from outside, this is not even related to threads. You need to turn them into instance fields in order to be able to access them, and then there's the tricky part - you need to learn about synchronization.

Comment: Here's the tutorial, it goes through the basics before getting into threading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you everyone that replied, I realize, that my question wasn't well constructed and I shouldn't be asking questions about threads, when I haven't cleared up my confusement with local variables and other basic concepts.